# Is the word " clean off" an adverb in the sentence below?

Tags: grammar, meaning, meaning-in-context, grammaticality, grammaticality-in-context

'It( his hand ) froze, and would have dropped **clean off**, if—' He shivered suddenly, and continued to shiver as if he felt the cold again.

Comment: _Clean_ is an adverb (an informal way of saying 'completely'). _Drop off_ is a phrasal verb.

Comment: @KateBunting thank you so much. I guessed that 'clean off' means something like ' completely ' but i didn't notice  that 'drop off' was a phrasal verb and 'clean' an adverb.thanks again

Comment: That's wrong. "Drop off" is not here a phrasal verb.

Comment: This is asking about grammar, not meaning, and should not be closed as asking about meaning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *It (his hand ) froze, and would have dropped* [*clean off ...*]

The adverb is just "clean". It's modifying the preposition "off" to form the preposition phrase "clean off" (meaning "completely off") functioning as complement of "dropped".

Comment: thank you so much. Based on another answer mentioned in the comment section above , shouldn't we consider  ' drop off ' a phrasal verb and ' clean ' an adverb ?

Comment: @SoGh Yes, as I said, "clean" is an adverb. "Drop off" is not a phrasal verb here. I don't use the term 'phrasal verb'. It's a misnomer: it's not the whole expression "drop off" that is a verb; it's just the word "drop". "Off" is a preposition functioning as complement of drop.